# What is the internal representation of inf and NaN?

Tags: fortran

A friend & I were debating how Inf's and NaN's are stored during lunch today.

Take Fortran 90 for example.  4-byte reals can obtain the value of Inf or NaN.  How is this stored internally?  Presumably, a 4-byte real is a number represented internally by a 32 digit binary number.  Are Inf's and NaN's stored as 33 bit binary numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Specifically from Pesto's [link](http://www.psc.edu/general/software/packages/ieee/ieee.php):

The IEEE single precision floating point standard representation requires a 32 bit word, which may be represented as numbered from 0 to 31, left to right. The first bit is the sign bit, `S`, the next eight bits are the exponent bits, '`E`', and the final 23 bits are the fraction '`F`':

```
S EEEEEEEE FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  
0 1      8 9                    31
```

The value `V` represented by the word may be determined as follows:

- If `E=255` and `F` is nonzero, then `V=NaN` ("Not a number")
- If `E=255` and `F` is zero and `S` is `1`, then `V=-Infinity`
- If `E=255` and `F` is zero and `S` is `0`, then `V=Infinity`
- If `0<E<255` then `V=(-1)**S * 2 ** (E-127) * (1.F)` where "`1.F`" is intended to represent the binary number created by prefixing F with an implicit leading 1 and a binary
  point.
- If `E=0` and `F` is nonzero, then `V=(-1)**S * 2 ** (-126) * (0.F)` These
  are "unnormalized" values.
- If `E=0` and `F` is zero and `S` is `1`, then `V=-0`
- If `E=0` and `F` is zero and `S` is `0`, then `V=0`

Answer (score 9):

Most floating point representations are based upon the IEEE standard, which has [set patterns](http://web.archive.org/web/20120124062928/http://www.psc.edu/general/software/packages/ieee/ieee.php) defined for Inf and NaN.