# In Python 3.8, what should be the correct result of -math.inf + math.inf?

Tags: python-3.x, infinite

In Python 3.8, when I run: -math.inf + math.inf ==> I am getting "nan".

Should the result be: 0? Or what is the rational for Python to produce "nan" for this addition?

Comment: I'd look at the IEEE math rules for that operation.

Comment: Here link to the [IEEE standard on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#2019). You might also be intrested in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151158/how-are-nan-and-infinity-of-a-float-or-double-stored-in-memory) explaining the bit representation of `+inf`, `-inf` and `NaN` and providing further links.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical terms Infinity is not a definable number.  You're thinking of it as "a really big number that has a value".  It doesn't.  (Infinity * Infinity) is still Infinity.  Don't try to mentally assign a real value to this.  The "nan" value makes sense as any math with Infinity (or `math.inf` in this case) really makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense -- thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I've another question regarding math.inf in Python:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595929/in-python-how-to-override-the-arithmetic-operator-to-produce-1-0-math

Comment: Are you saying [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) can't be done?