# In Python, how to override the arithmetic operator "/" to produce: 1 / 0 => math.inf?

Tags: python-3.x, operator-overloading, overriding

In Python, when I run the operation: 1 / 0, its default behavior is generating an exception: "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"

How to overload this default behavior so that I can get:
1 / 0 => math.inf

Comment: In this case mathematically `1/0` *should* be infinity.  But every programming language I've ever used generates a similar error as Python does in this case.  Remember, though, you can't check for equality with `math.inf`.  Even if it did return `math.inf` you can't say something like `result = 1/0` and then `if result == math.inf:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own class and within that define methods `__truediv__` (`/`) and `__floordiv__` (`//`) at a minimum. If you only define those two `+` for example would not work (see error below).

```py
import math


class MyFloat:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if other.val == 0:
            return math.inf
        return self.val / other.val

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        if other.val == 0:
            return math.inf
        return self.val // other.val


one = MyFloat(1)
zero = MyFloat(0)

print(one / zero)
print(one // zero)
// will throw an error (PyCharm will also pick up on this)
print(one + zero)
```

Expected output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/Dev/Studium/test/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(one + zero)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MyFloat' and 'MyFloat'
inf
inf
```

For a list of those *special* Python function see [this website](https://www.askpython.com/python/operator-overloading-in-python).

Comment: This is indeed what I'm looking for -- thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you might have to write your own library that allows this to happen, it might not be too hard to make something simple that sees when you get that error and instead assigns that number to 'infinity'